# what is the usage of :type in defcustom?

Tags: emacs, customization

I am not sure I understand the property `type` in `defcustom`. I can perfectly define the following variables without conforming to the `type`. what is the purpose of `type` in this context?

```
(defcustom foo 1 "foo" :type 'string)
(defcustom spam "a" "foo" :type 'integer)
```

Comment: It's `'integer`, not `'int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the type for integer is `integer`, not `int`, so your specific example will not work with Customize.

The `:type` determines the edit control used, and provides completion and type checking when saving customization:

## Edit control

`M-x customize-variable` picks an edit control which is best suited to enter a value for the expected type.  For instance, a `boolean` type becomes a toggle button, simple types as `integer` or `string` get a line edit, `choice` becomes a value menu, `set` a list of checkboxes, etc.

## Completion

Within certain edit controls, Customize provides completion.  For instance, when you press `M-Tab` in a line edit for a `function` type (as used for hook variables), Customize automatically completes function names.  If there is more than one matching name, you'll see a pop up buffer with all completion candidates.  Likewise, a `color` widget provides you with completion for all known color names.

## Type checking

For all edit controls, Customize checks the type of the current value before saving, and refuses to apply any customization with a non-matching type.

For instance, if you enter a non-numeric into an `integer` widget, and try to apply or save the customization, Customize will refuse to do so and signal a “This field should contain an integer” error.

Comment: For tons more details, see the [Customization Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customization-Types.html) section of the Emacs Lisp manual.

Answer (score 4):

As the Elisp manual (node `Variable Definitions`) says: ***It specifies which values are legitimate, and how to display the value.***"

This affects "appropriate edit control for the user to customize with", as @amalloy says.  It affects also whether Customize shows the current value as valid for the `:type` or is a type mismatch.

In sum, it provides type-checking and editing assistance for users, and it determines how Customize displays the value (as a Lisp value, Boolean, etc.).

Comment: For tons more details, see the [Customization Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customization-Types.html) section of the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: @chwarr: Absolutely. Thanks for adding that link.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `:type` causes `customize-variable` to present an appropriate edit control for the user to customize with.

Comment: it seems no matter what `type` is used, there is no different in `customize-variable`

Comment: @RNA Try with more complex values (e.g. `choice` versus `repeat`).  Also, `customize-variable` should refuse to save when you enter a string into a `integer` field.